# Trying to find with $regex multiple fields at the same time in Mongodb

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I am trying to develope a searcher in my web app, i am using mongodb... so... i have a document, with this information.

```
{
    "_id": "458734895734",
    "name": "user",
    "ref": "1",
    "data": "fdnsfkjndjfn"
},
{
    "_id": "3332423333",
    "name": "user1",
    "ref": "2",
    "data": "dvsdvdvds"
}
```

i am using $regex for match the search with my app. so i have this in my server node.js.

```
db.users.find({ 
    name: {'$regex': query, '$options': 'i'}
}).then((users) => {
    res.json(users);
})

        // var query, is just the pattern that i send from my web
```

As you can see, my server is only searching in the field 'name', how can i add other field like 'ref' and search in both fields at the same time?? i've checking the documentation in mongodb but i could not find it...

Answer (score 27, accepted):

This is because the way you wrote the query which means it should match the given `regex` query with all passed parameter like and(&&) operation. What you could do is make and or(||) operation with all the required fields.

Here the sample code you can try.

```
db.users.find({
    "$or": [
        { name: { '$regex': query, '$options': 'i' } },
        { ref: { '$regex': query, '$options': 'i' } }
    ]
}).then((users) => {
    res.json(users);
});
```

Comment: perfect ! exactly, i was missing OR operator... thank you!

Comment: @pavan-vora I'm with a similar problem, but in my case `name` and `ref` could be anything. Is it possible to handle that?

Answer (score -2):

The OR operator, regex or options doesn't need to be in quotes. Below works for me:

```
db.users.find({
$or: [
    { name: { $regex: query, $options: 'i' } },
    { ref: { $regex: query, $options: 'i' } }
]
}).then((users) => {
    res.json(users); 
});
```